# should i make different images for each folder in an android application?(hdpi,mdpi,ldpi)

Tags: size, sprite, image, hdpi, mdpi

I want to develop a game but I'm not sure about the sizes of the pics.
I checked the app after I finished one animation on my phone and on my emulator; the pics changed their size by themselves. Then should i make the same pic with different size for each folder on one pic with the same size and put it in each of the folders.
thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[You don't *have* to](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/providing-resources.html#BestMatch), but it can be useful: sometimes it's better to use a simpler image at small resolutions, and that's where the different densities are helpful.

It also allows more fine-grained control of scaling: if you only provide a hdpi version, a lot of detail can be lost if it has to scale that image significantly. By providing a ldpi version, you can provide a clean base picture which won't need to be scaled as much; resulting in fewer potential scaling artifacts (but unless the other versions are cleaned up a bit, you probably won't see much of a difference in the end).

Comment: Thanks, I'm going to use only the hdpi for now and maybe create the others later!